# Solve first order PDE in mathematica. (Routine economics problem, HJB)

Tags: differential-equations

This problem has a known closed form solution, but Mathematica is having trouble solving it.

```
(*write pde & boundary condition*)
eq2 = rho*V[t, a] == ( D[V[t, a], a] )^((gg - 1)/gg)/(1 - gg) + 
D[V[t, a], a]*(y + r*a - ( D[V[t, a], a] )^(-1/gg)) + 
D[V[t, a], t];
bc2 = V[T, a] == 0;

(*Try analytical*) 
sola = DSolve[{eq2, bc2}, V[t, a], {t, a}]
(*unable to solve*)

(*plug in param*)
rho = 0.01; gg = 2.0; y = 10.0; r = 0.03; T = 20.0;
sola = DSolve[{eq2, bc2}, V[t, a], {t, a}]
(*unable to solve*)

(*Try to solve numerically*)
soln = NDSolve[{eq2, bc2}, V[t, a], {t, 0, T}, {a, 0, 75}]

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^0.5 encountered.
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^0.5 encountered.
General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation.    
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.    
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.    
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.    
General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.   
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 20.`.    
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 20.`.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here is the closed-form solution:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the closed form solution so we can easily check?

Comment: @xzczd good idea, just added!

Comment: When `gg=2` the solution doesn't hold: `Vsol[t_, a_] = 
  With[{omega = r - (r - rho)/gg}, (a + y/r)^(1 - gg)/(
    1 - gg) ((1 - Exp[-omega (T - t)])/omega)^gg]; eq2 /. V -> Vsol /. gg -> 2 /. rho -> 1/100 /. y -> 10 /. r -> 3/100 /. T -> 20 // Simplify` If I guess it right, `gg` should be between `0` and `1`.

Comment: It actually works for all gg>0.
Only issue is when gg>1, V[t,a] will be negative (but increasing).

Comment: I apologize if I'm wrong. gg in your code is the risk aversion index, right? I don't think it exceeds 1.

Comment: Yes, it's risk aversion and it can exceed 1